# Featherlight Plugin - sw.js file from youtube opening chrome inspector

Tags: jquery, html, css

was wondering might know what might be happening here. I am using featherweight the plugin to display youtube videos in an Iframe.

But if you close the lightbox before the sw.js file is loaded. It then opens up the sw.js file in a separate inspector window. I have attached 3 screenshots to further explain the problem.

st screenshot - This is the network when calling the embedded youtube video. As you can see, the sw.js file has loaded. If you close it, then it works fine.

2nd screenshot - This is the network when calling the embedded youtube video. You can see here that the sw.js file has not loaded. When you close the lightbox before it has loaded, then the sw.js file opens up in a separate inspector window, see screenshot 3.

3rd screenshot - You can see that the inspector has opened the sw.js file has opened in a new inspector window.

I should also add that when calling a new featherweight I use the root option to change the root of the lightbox and the beforeOpen option to close the previous featherweight lightbox using '$.featherlight.close();'.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

[Link to featherlight plugin](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight)

Comment: I also have this when using Fancybox 3, so it may not be specific to featherlight.